# Why getting image X,Y pixel color not working in this example?

Tags: jquery, html, image-processing

I am trying to get image X,Y pixel color using example provided in this answer (http://goo.gl/9OZp1P).

```
$('#map').mousemove(function(e) {          
            if(!this.canvas) {
                this.canvas = $('<canvas/>').css({width:this.width + 'px', height: this.height + 'px'})[0];
                this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            }
            var pixelData = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            console.log(pixelData);

            $('#output').html("X coordinate: "+event.offsetX+"<br>Y coordinate: "+event.offsetY+"<br>RED: "+pixelData[0]);
        });
```

Have copied the code but it only shows color of some portion of image in upper left corner and everything else is zeros (for RGB). What have I done wrong?

As Fidle does not allow to upload images and grabbing color of image from different host is not allowed, please find live code here: http://wilkas.comxa.com/pixel_info.html

Copy on Fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/wilkas/MWa3k/ (not working due image on different host).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the `width` and `height` *properties* of the Canvas to be the same as the image, not its CSS values.

The properties determine the actual number of pixels and will default to 300x150 if not explicitly specified.    The CSS determine the coordinate mapping from screen pixels to canvas pixels.

If you look carefully at your coordinates you will find that only values up to 300x150 are being retrieved correctly.

```
this.canvas.width = this.width;
this.canvas.height = this.height;
```

Do ensure that your image is actually loaded, first!

Comment: I think that it is the same thing what user "fabspro" said in his subcomment (in http://goo.gl/9OZp1P), but his line of code does not work. Could you please update your answer to include code which shows how to update Canvas properties? You could also update suggestion in afore mentioned topic and take the credits for it:)

Comment: @wilkas the updated code in that answer actually appears correct

Comment: Yes, it seems that answer itself is correct, but jQuery example in Fiddle is not updated accordingly. And I didn't look close at answer code, because it was in native JavaScript. Thanks again. Now my idea when black-white image gets saturated when user clicks in right spot  (by checking pixel color of a hidden map) is working :)